# Get data from server function in client component

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, app-router

I'm trying to get data from a server function in a client component, but I get a maximum call stack size exceeded error.

My client component (@/app/dashboard/page.js):

```js
"use client"

import { getLoad } from "@/actions/loads"
import LoadItem from "@/components/load-item"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function Home() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(function() {
        (async function() {
            setData(await getLoad())
        })()
    }, [])

    return (
        <ul>
            {data.map(load => (
                <LoadItem key={load._id} load={load}  />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

And my server function (@/actions/loads.js):

```js
"use server"

import connect from "@/helpers/db"
import Loaddata from "@/models/loaddata"

export async function getLoad(id) {
    await connect()

    if (id) {
        const data = await Loaddata.findById(id)
        return data
    }

    const data = await Loaddata.find({})
    return data
}
```

I wonder if it might have to do with mongoose/mongodb and the nature of the extra layer of asynchronicity, cause if I test the above example and just return a hard-coded object or array, I don't get this error.

However, this works fine if I just use server components instead of client, and simply call `await getLoad()` without states or useEffect.

Comment: I suspect you have a recursion issue i.e. you have an endless loop.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, @jQueeny, just not sure where it occurs, or why. The error stack tells me nothing.